# Что значит в Python if value==()?

Tags: python

Не пойму чему пытается узнать равно value в `if value == ()`

вот пример кода где это встречается

```
@_SpecialForm
def Union(self, parameters):

    if parameters == ():
        raise TypeError("Cannot take a Union of no types.")
```

что здесь означает  `if parameters == ():`

Comment: `()` это пустой кортеж, а что такое `==` по-моему должно быть очевидно

Comment: Понял , если значение parametres равно пустому кортежу, тогда сгенерировать исключение TypeError?

Comment: Но если `parameters` будет не пустой кортеж, а, например, пустой список, то проверка не сработает, так что код наверное плохонький и лучше было бы написать `if not parameters:` или типа того

Comment: Не знаю даже, это код в библиотеке typing. Там дальше идёт     if not isinstance(parameters, tuple):
        parameters = (parameters,)
    msg = "Union[arg, ...]: each arg must be a type."
    parameters = tuple(_type_check(p, msg) for p in parameters)
    parameters = _remove_dups_flatten(parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if value == () переводится как "Если Value равно пустому кортежу"

Вот ссылка про них https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/kortezhi-tuple.html